# How to explain why there are leopards in Southern California?

Tags: post-apocalypse, fauna

So, in my post apocalyptic world, I plan for Southern California to be a tribal, wild landscape full of wild animals and equally wild people. I plan on having only small communities and tribes, and in between those communities, in the large patches of wild untamed lands, I want to have a few exotic creatures stalking the waste. One animal I really want to have is a Leopard, as they are my favorite animal. But, this is Southern California we’re talking about. So, is there a plausible reason for why leopards would be in Southern California?

Comment: Reminder (this is at least the 5th time I've seen you reminded of this, btw); proper use of they're, there, and their is important. Also, asking "so do you guys have ideas" is literally textbook too broad and POB

Comment: There are leopards in Southern California right now. More specifically in the San Diego zoo apparently. The plausible reason is that before the apocalyspe, people liked zoos with exotic animals.  ...

Comment: @Raditz_35's comment is a pretty good answer.  You could say the apocalypse changed the environment such that S. CA. becomes more tropical and the leopards (aka, Jaguars) migrated north - but everything else tropical would migrate north, too (often just ahead of the Jaguars).  Thus, the question is more, "how do I exclude what I don't want" than it is "How do I get what I want."

Comment: I don't usually vote down questions I VTC, but as @Aify says, you keep repeating the same issues and your questions do not improve.  You seem to be actually refusing to learn from past votes to close your questions and in some ways this is almost trolling the community.  Please spend longer learning what good questions look like and how to avoid breaking the rules.

Answer (score 3):

Jaguars look rather similar to leopards at first glance (they both have spots)

[image]

Southern California is within their [historic range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaguar#/media/File:Panthera_onca_distribution.svg).

They are, of course, not as fast as leopards.

Answer (score 1):

The [Los Angeles Zoo](https://www.lazoo.org/2017/09/snow-leopard-cubs/) and the [San Diego Zoo](http://animals.sandiegozoo.org/animals/leopard) are both sources of leopards in California.

BTW, the San Diego Zoo link has some good info on the diet and habitats of leopards.  Those might help your story.

Also, don't overlook collectors with more money than ethics or brains.  There might be some unofficial sources of leopards in the hills.